# Align content in a container, and wrap conditionally

Tags: css

I'm building a project, and in order to save some space, I'd like to position my content like so:

In other words:

1. The `Element A` should always align to the right, below the text
2. Should "float" right whenever there's enough space (first two examples)
3. Wrap to next line when there isn't space (the bottom example).

So far, I've tried two different ways, and both ways there's something that's not quite right. [Here's a JSBin](https://jsbin.com/kebiqeh/edit?html,css,output).

In the first option, the Siblings, 2nd and 3rd are not quite right: the "Element A" isn't "floating" (it's like there's two columns).

In the second option, the Inline, 2nd and 3rd are right, but the first one is not ("Element A" is stuck to the left).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Add width: 100% to the p element

```css
.container div {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 260px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.container div p {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .elem {
  border: 1px solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.container div p a {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h2>Inline (Parent/Child)</h2>
    <div>
      <p class="text">Short text <a class="elem">Elemente A</a></p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="text">Longer text that wraps two lines but then stops. <a class="elem">Elemente A</a></p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p class="text">Longer text that wraps two lines, and keeps going till the end, and some more. <a class="elem">Elemente A</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply floating the `<a>` to the right and [clear-fixing](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) the parent seems to give what you want:

```css
.container div {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  width: 260px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  clear: both;
}

.container div:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.container .elem {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Inline (Parent/Child)</h2>
  <div>
    <p class="text">Short text <a class="elem">Elemente A</a></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="text">Longer text that wraps two lines but then stops. <a class="elem">Elemente A</a></p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p class="text">Longer text that wraps two lines, and keeps going till the end, and some more. hmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm<a class="elem">Elemente A</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `display: flex;`, `float: left;` etc seems unnecessary.